# Unattended download from Google Cloud Storage or Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

First, the system architecture:
Server: Running IIS ASP and delivering data to a hundred or so WinXP+ clients in the field upon automated requests from those clients. Data sent from the server is large graphic or video files. If a file is placed on the server by a user, these remote clients will "discover" it and download the file.

Clients: As stated above, the clients are remote unattended boxes that fetch content from the server. The end purpose is digital signage.

Problem: All clients hitting the server at the same time makes for slow transfers of large files - not enough bandwidth.

Solution (I think): Use Google Cloud Storage or Google Drive to hold the files and have the clients request (automated and unattended) those files. I think Google would have a higher available bandwidth (at least the NSA thinks so).

**Questions:**
Which is a better solution between Google Cloud Storage and Google Drive?

Is it possible to use Windows PowerShell or WScript to run scripts to interact with Google? Reason is that I need to avoid installing new software on the client machines that might require user interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use powershell as long as you can urlfetch https data. The oauth flow might be tricky to get working, follow examples for installed apps.
100% use cloud storage instead of drive. Drive is not meant to scale with simultaneous downloads and has several quotas so you will need to implement exponential backoff etc with drive.

Comment: TNX - Cloud storage does, indeed, seem to be the most robust solution. I just need to be able to do it on the client side without the need for a human at the keyboard on that end (there is no keyboard, no mouse, no human)

Comment: its possible, except for the first time when you need to authorize from a browser. once you have the oauth tokens there is no human interaction. explaining how to is beyond this question scope, look at how to do oauth2.0

Comment: TNX Zig - Human interaction at the outset is not possible in my situation in most cases. Some of the client computers are buried in racks that haven't seen a human is years. They just keep on running. Still, some can be accessed via Remote Desktop so I could do the authorization on those. My first play-session with Google Cloud the other day presented my with the authorization challenge you mentioned. Somehow, need to figure out how to script a response...

Comment: for the authorization part, just make an appengine with a public (but hard to guess) url, and have that url give you the data you need (like the list or url to your cloud storage, which will have public permission too).

Comment: Sorry this took almost 2 years to come back with a comment to close this out. Things are evolving but the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Drive or Cloud Storage. I would go for Drive over Cloud Storage, because :-

1. It's free, Cloud Storage will cost you and so you have to worry about your credit card expiring
2. It's easier to program since it's a simple http GET to retrieve your files
3. 1. You need to think about your security model. With Drive you **could** (nb not should), make the files public. Provided your clients can be informed of the URL, then there is no OAuth to worry about. If you need better security, install a Refresh Token on each client. Before each download, your client will make a call to Google to convert the refresh token to an access token. I suggest prototype without OAuth to begin with. Then if (a) it fits, and (b) you need more security, add OAuth.
4. The Drive web app gives you your management console for the downloadable files. If you use Cloud Storage, you'll need to write your own.

The quota issue is discussed here [Google Drive as a video hosting/streaming platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831838/google-drive-as-a-video-hosting-streaming-platform) 
Because the quota isn't documented, we can only guess at what the restrictions are. It seems to be bandwidth for a given file, so the larger the file, the fewer the number of downloads. A simple workaround is to use the copy API https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy to make multiple copies of the file.

You have other options too. Since these are simply static files, you could host them on Google Sites or Google App Engine. you could also store them within App Engine datastore which has a free quota.

Finally, you could even consider a BitTorrent approach.

Comment: I've updated my answer. While doing some research, I've seen reports of quota related errors for multi-megabyte files, which might impact your scenario. Unfortunately these quotas aren't documented.

Comment: TNX - For practice, I might try Drive but, as I am a business and need to adopt a true business solution, I suspect Cloud is my ultimate solution. That said, you comments are helpful as well as the links. True, other options are available (BitTorrent, et al). My #1 requirement is that the client systems must be able to implement this "change in procedure" without needing a human at the keyboard. I have Remote Desktop into only a limited few. I can do a heck-of-a-lot using BAT files I sent to the systems.

Comment: You can generate a refresh token centrally and embed it in your code so your remote clients can do human-less oauth of that's the path you go down.

Comment: Drive is NOT the way to go, you will run into multiple quotas as drive is meant to be a personal service and the quotas are there to prevent abuse. See my answer.

Comment: Maybe you should tell Google that. See https://googledrive.com/host/0B716ywBKT84AMXBENXlnYmJISlE/GoogleDriveHosting.html